# How To Generate Sql script from database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have Configured server database with My SQL server 2014. My database montage name. 
i have not seen my table in left object explorer . but i have use select query its showing Results but  i can't able view table left side.
 please any one tell me how to generate Full script my server database.  Even also i cant able  to see tasks  also .. please any one tell i want generate full script .

and tired to  get script from i can't able . even i  tired stored procedure  got script using `"Sp_helpText"`  . how to get script from table using query

Comment: Try refresh or f5 in object explorer.

Comment: i can view  when i connect local db not view after connect server database

Comment: There is not such thing as My Sql Server. It's either MySql or Sql Server.

Comment: sql server 2014 using